Squirrel Logger isn't logging (How to Log using Squirrel Mail)
I have a squirrel mail mail server and am trying to log when my users are opening emails, and which users they are.
I tried using the plugin squirrel logger (and following the INSTALL directions) but it isn't logging anything.
I checked the apache2 access.log file but it doesn't specify exactly what I want, it shows login times though. Let me know if I'm posting this in the wrong place. How should I go about timestamping and logging when my users are opening emails? (I have already setup the mail server and don't intend on switching to a different client for this)
